# Search resource in GREG 4.1.1

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

I added resource to GREG from file. I can search and find this resource by name, but can not find this resource by content.

Comment: @thusharaK since you are tagging all these questions with `wso2greg`, you should create a tag wiki.

Comment: @royhowie done! waiting for peer reviewed.

Answer (score 0):

Created a JIRA for this, https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-12762 Meanwhile could you please check with the latest snapshot from here http://wso2.org/bamboo/browse/WSO2CARBON-PRODUCTS-16/artifact/JOB1/GREG too.

Thanks